# Set tick values in ggbreak

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am using the command `scale_x_break` to set an axis break in a ggplot. However, the current code has way too many tick marks in the "extreme values" section after the axis break. The command contains an argument `ticklabels`, however for some reason, I cannot use this to change the "extreme" tick marks, i.e., -1000, -1010, -1020, -1030, -1040, and -1050. This command however, does work well in adding/removing tick marks "before" the axis break. Case in point: the section of code `ticklabels = c(-5, -1015)` *adds* a tick mark for -5 and removes all other tick marks **before** the axis break, but does not add the -1015 or remove any tick marks after the axis break.

Ideally, the "extreme" panel would have 3 tick marks: -1000, -1025, and -1050.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbreak) 
library(patchwork)

x1 <- c('A', 'B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G')
y1 <- c(-9.375783475,   6.21616158, -19.32680732,   -8.727239523,   13.93210958,    -1051.866122,   -75.11041633)
df1 <- data.frame(x1, y1)

p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(y1, x1)) + geom_col(orientation="y")
p2 <- p1 + scale_x_break(c(-1000, -80), ticklabels = c(-5, -1015)) + xlab("relative variable importance") + ylab("commodity network")

p2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `scale_x_continuous` with specified breaks to `p2`

```r
p2 + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-1000, -1025, -1050))
```

[image]